# Page list incomplete on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I use Facebook SDK to publish on pages.
I've successfully added them to my app and done some posts.

However, access token on those pages have expired and now, when I try to add them again, they aren't showing in page list selection :

[image: w]

I'm still admin on those pages, but the only way to see them again is to delete the app from my Facebook profile and ask a new token.

I have 6 pages and on first access token demand, they are all showing.
When I ask again for access token, only 2 pages are showing (always the same pages).

So, on 2nd time :

- if continue the process with one page selected, the token is renewed for this page only and I lose access to other pages.
- if I check "All Pages", the token is renewed for all pages, even the invisibles ones.
- If I check nothing, I lose access on all pages

Comment: There should be no need to select a page you already selected before, again at this point. Have you tried what happens if you just clicked “Next” here …?

Comment: @misorude I've added more information

Comment: Try adding `auth_type=rerequest` to the login dialog call, it appears the whole list of pages gets presented again then.

Comment: @misorude Doesn't work, I've tried to add `auth_type=rerequest`in URL and also to replace `getLoginUrl()` by `getReRequestUrl()`